# GridLayout в ScrollView выдает ошибку

Tags: java, android

Получил много ошибок, но считаю что основная эта, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.kalinwallik.csgoinfo, PID: 25717 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 28545036 byte allocation with 4176736 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
```

Приложение просто вылетает при переходе на это активити

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_info__map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.kalinwallik.csgoinfo.Info_Map"
tools:showIn="@layout/main_info_map"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="580dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_dust_two"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button_dusttwo" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_mirage"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button_mirage" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_cache"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button_cache" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_inferno"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button_inferno" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_train"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button_train" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_overpass"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button_overpass" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_cobston"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button_cobston" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m_nuke"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button_nuke" />
    </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, укажите какая ошибка возникает.

Comment: Добрый день Дима.Знаешь найти ошибку это одно дело но надо знать ошибку.посмотри лог и выложи сюда

Comment: Проверяю через реальное устройство, нажимаю на кнопку которая переводит на эту активити и приложение закрывается с ошибкой

Comment: Чтоб узнать где ошибка внизу на панеле в AndidStudio есть раздел AndroidMonitor перейди туда и там будет процесс работы ввмя ошибки ты заметишь её скопируй и выставь сюда

Comment: Добавилли ты  активость в манифест?

Comment: сперва протестируй на эмуляторе

Comment: @elik Во что выдает 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.kalinwallik.csgoinfo, PID: 25717
                                                                          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 28545036 byte allocation with 4176736 free bytes and 3MB until OOM

И еще большой столбец ошибок

Comment: Ну а тебя OutOfMemoryError: не смутило ?)вставляй свой код ты его нагрузил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ошибка нехватки памяти для разворачивание битмапов для `ImageButton`.

Видимо, вы не озаботились маппингом битмапов в зависимости от *density*

Прогоните свои битмапы через [эту тулзу](https://github.com/patrickfav/density-converter) и разбросайте по `drawable-hdpi/mdpi` и проч.

Comment: Я не давно в этом программировании , если я разбросаю по 'drawable-hdpi/mdpi' то из 'drawable0' можно удалить или оставить?

Comment: Можно оставить.

Comment: mipmap-hdpi и darawadle-hdpi одно и тоже?

Comment: По моему мипмэп для картинок в стиле флэт дизайна а драваблы для фотографий например